# What is the order to style a div inside of tables?

Tags: html, css

`#div` that holds table, table tr td.class of td now what goes here to style a div class I put inside of the td class?

Comment: It might help clarify if you write a bit of code in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
td.class-of-td div.class-of-div {
    // Style of div of class "class-of-div" inside a td of class "class-of-td".
}
```

Comment: gotcha so when I do div where you said, its a class. so do I do

table tr td.class #name of div in table?

or 
table tr td.class .name of div in table?

cause its a div class

Comment: To refer to `<div class='xyz'>` you need to say `div.xyz`.

Answer (score 2):

If your code looks like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td class="somecell">
             <div>some text</div>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

.. then this CSS selector should do the trick:

```
#mydiv table tr td.somecell div
```

**[Edited according to comment]**

I'm not really sure what you mean, but I guess you should read up a little on CSS selectors :)

`#` represents an ID

`.` represents a class

The basic syntax of a selector is somewhat like this:

```
[Type][[# or .][name]] [.. next selector]
```

For example:

```
div#mydiv
```

.. will select a div with an Id of mydiv.

```
#mydiv
```

.. will select any object with an Id of mydiv

You can cascade the selectors by adding spaces between them, so:

```
div table.bluetable
```

.. will select all tables with a class of "bluetable" whose parent is a div.

---

Now, if I understood your comment correct, your code looks like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td class="somecell">
             <div class="somediv">some text</div>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

.. then your selector would be

```
#mydiv table tr td.somecell div.somediv
```

Or in case you don't care about the class of the td's

```
#mydiv table tr td div.somediv
```

And in case you just want all divs with class="somediv"

```
div.somediv
```

Hope it helps :)

Try one of the guides here: [google search](http://www.google.dk/search?hl=da&safe=off&q=css+selector+tutorial&meta=)

Comment: gotcha so when I do div where you said, its a class. so do I do

table tr td.class #name of div in table?

or 
table tr td.class .name of div in table?

cause its a div class

Comment: Updated with a better explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

table tr td.class div

Comment: gotcha so when I do div where you said, its a class. so do I do

table tr td.class #name of div in table?

or 
table tr td.class .name of div in table?

cause its a div class